# Variant Column Aggregation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate, variant

In source we have a variant column (events) and we need to sum up metrics (calls, impressions, leads, visits, etc.) in that column.

Tricky part here is that variant column can have new metrics added anytime and we dont want to update our code (stored procedure) every time.

Is there a way we can dynamically add metrics within variant column(events) to target variant column(total_events) without any code change?
Source:
[image]

Required Target:
[image]

SQL for setting up source data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE user_activity (
    ACTIVITY DATE,
    ID       NUMBER  , 
    NAME     VARCHAR , 
    EVENTS   VARIANT
);

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events) 
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 101, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 1,   "calls": 0,   "leads": 0 }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events) 
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 102, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 1,   "calls": 0,   "leads": 0 }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 103, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 0,   "calls": 1,   "leads": 0 }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 104, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 0,   "calls": 0,   "leads": 1 }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-06'::date, 105, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 0,   "calls": 0,   "leads": 1,   "service": 1 }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-06'::date, 106, 'Mickey Mouse', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": 1,   "visits": 1,   "calls": 0 }');

SELECT * FROM user_activity ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Here is work in progress (from another post, apologies for duplicated entries):

```
select 
    activity     as activity
  , name         as name
  , OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 
                  'calls',   sum(a.calls::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'imps',    sum(a.imps::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'leads',   sum(a.leads::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'visits',  sum(a.visits::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'service', sum(a.service::NUMBER(2,1))
                  ) AS total_events
from (
    SELECT
        activity       AS activity
      , name           AS name
      , events         AS events 
      , events:calls   AS calls
      , events:imps    AS imps
      , events:leads   AS leads
      , events:visits  AS visits
      , events:service AS service
    FROM user_activity,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(events, OUTER=> TRUE) f
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
) a
group by 1,2
order by 1,2,3;
```

I want SQL something like this (dummy sql) where I don't have to list down metrics embedded in variant column.

```
SELECT activity, SUM(events) AS total_events
FROM user_activity
GROUP BY activity;
```

Comment: "*Is there a way ... without any code change?*" How can we tell you if a code change is or is not required if we cannot see the code? (But my guess is "No, you will need a code change.")  If you normalised that data it would probably make the data maintenance task easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably gives you what you want:

```
with flat_data as (
SELECT
        activity       AS activity
      , name           AS name
      ,f.key
      ,f.value
    FROM user_activity,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(events, OUTER=> TRUE) f
)
, sum_data as (
SELECT
    activity
    ,name
    ,key
    ,sum(value)::INTEGER as value
FROM
    flat_data
GROUP BY
    activity, name, key
)
SELECT
    activity
    ,name
    ,OBJECT_AGG(key, value) TOTAL_EVENTS
from sum_data
group by activity, name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with one level query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.activity       
 ,a.name
 ,OBJECT_AGG(s.key, SUM(s.value::INT)) OVER(PARTITION BY a.activity, a.name) AS total_events
FROM user_activity AS a
,LATERAL FLATTEN(events, OUTER=> TRUE) AS s
GROUP BY a.activity, a.name, s.key;
```

Output:

[image]

Side note: Combining DISTINCT/aggregate/window function may not be more performant that simple double aggregation and CTE!